# Is it possible (and even correct) to calculate a confidence interval from an interpolated value?

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, probit, interpolation

I am using a probit model to calculate the limit of detection of a diagnostic test. For this, in R, I used `glm()`:

```
# Some dummy, made up data
data <- data.frame(conc = 1e3/(2 ** c(seq(0, 9))), detected = c(100, 99, 92, 85, 70, 50, 30, 21, 12, 0), failed = 100 - c(100, 99, 92, 85, 70, 50, 30, 21, 12, 0))

# Fitting a probit model
model <- glm(cbind(detected, failed) ~ log10(conc), data = data, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

And then I use the adjusted model to predict the concentration (the independent variable) in which the predicted detection rate (the dependent variable) is 95%:

```
lod95 <- 10^((model$family$linkfun(0.95) - coef(model)[1])/coef(model)[2])
```

So far, so good. Now, to the question: how do I calculate the error of this interpolation? In other words, how do I calculate the 95% confidence interval for the concentration estimated above?

I did a bit of research about this, and most answers I got refer to the error in y for a given x. What I need is the error in x for a given y.

I have read somewhere that I could flip the model in the `glm` call to something like `glm(log10(conc) ~ cbind(detected, failed), ...)`, but it just seems weird.

I'm not so familiar with all the concepts, so and any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, even if it just helps me to ask the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'calibration' or (perhaps more descriptively) an 'inverse regression' problem. That should guide you to some useful theoretical treatments.

Here's one of several straightforward ways to do it using the [investr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=investr) package that you can find from the [Chemometrics R Task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ChemPhys.html).

Setting up your problem in log10 space already to work around a package limitation:

```
data <- data.frame(conc = log10(1e3/(2 ** c(seq(0, 9)))), 
                   detected = c(100, 99, 92, 85, 70, 50, 30, 21, 12, 0), 
                   failed = 100 - c(100, 99, 92, 85, 70, 50, 30, 21, 12, 0))
> data
      conc detected failed
1  3.00000      100      0
2  2.69897       99      1
3  2.39794       92      8
4  2.09691       85     15
5  1.79588       70     30
6  1.49485       50     50
7  1.19382       30     70
8  0.89279       21     79
9  0.59176       12     88
10 0.29073        0    100

model <- glm(cbind(detected, failed) ~ conc, data = data, 
               family = binomial(link = "probit"))

coef(model)
(Intercept)        conc 
  -2.394905    1.636910
```

Do the calibration for 0.95 with a 95% interval on conc:

````
library(investr)

invest(model, y0 = 0.95)

> estimate    lower    upper 
2.467917 2.359199 2.597041 

# Am alternative method
invest(model, y0 = 0.95, interval = "Wald")

> estimate     lower     upper        se 
2.4679169 2.3500396 2.5857943 0.0601426 
```
````

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Thanks!